# Get value on Request - Kendo UI Dropdownlist ASP.NET MVC

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm searcing why the Kendo Dropdownlist box doesn't keep my value and pass it on the Request.

I have this on the chtml :

```
<form method="post" name="Lang">
Culture : @Culture

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("cbLanguage") 
.DataTextField("Name") 
.DataValueField("Culture") 
.BindTo(new List<Language>()
{
    new Language() {Name = "Français (Canada)", Culture = "fr-CA"},
    new Language() {Name = "English (Canada)", Culture = "en-CA"},
    new Language() {Name = "English (United State)", Culture = "en-US"}
})
.Events(e => e
    .Select("cbLanguage_select")
)
.Value(Culture)
)

<select name="lang" onchange="submitLang();">
    <option></option>
    <option value="en-US" @(Culture == "en-US" ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "")>English</option>
    <option value="fr-CA" @(Culture == "fr-CA" ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "")>French</option>
</select>
</form>

<script>

function cbLanguage_select(e) {
    $('form').submit();
};

function submitLang() {
    $('form').submit();
}
</script>
```

After that i put this code on the _ViewStart.

```
if (!Request["lang"].IsEmpty())
{
    Culture = UICulture = Request["lang"];
}
```

----  or this depend of each combo i want tested!!!!

```
if (!Request["cbLanguage"].IsEmpty())
{
    Culture = UICulture = Request["cbLanguage"];
}
```

It's work really fine with the standard combo. But i never receive the value on the Request with the Kendo Dropdownlist.

I need help to find why!!!

Thank you!

Comment: I have found the solution!  It's just the event! I need to use Change event, not the Select!  :-)